# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Error: 18452?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Here is part of the error message when I try to connect:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

How do I fix this? (this is a school SQL Server to work on so it should not be untrusted)

Comment: `Integrated Security=true`

Comment: Where do I change that?

Comment: Why was this changed to a duplicate? I am not trying to get into a server with code.